How to remove bold font from \title
I am trying to remove the Bold font from the title (i.e. to use normal unformatted text in the title). I tried putting \normalfont inside \title but it removes the Trajan Pro font.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times}
\newfontfamily{\trajan}{Trajan Pro}

\title{{\trajan The Wind Blows}} % Here \normalfont uses Times font, not Trajan

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}


Can you show a screenshot of what you get? I don't get a bold title.

Maybe \title{\trajan\textmd{The Wind Blows}}?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz you are right. I get different on different machines. On Archlinux, I get the bold font, but not on ubuntu..

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Maybe another version of Trajan Pro or XeLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX. For example the commercial version of Trajan Pro provides several more OTFs for several more weights. And with XeLaTeX I also get the correct result out of the box.

@cabohah lualatex, but I have both regular and bold installed as .otf.

If you are using LuaLaTeX you should have a look into the log file. It shows, which font files are used. In my case — using the free font from https://freefontsfamily.net/trajan-pro-font-free/ with LuaLaTeX — it automatically prefers the OTF file TrajanPro_Bold.otf as regular font, as noted at the end of the log file:
 1073 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 180 glue_spec, 5 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:170,3:62,4:4,5:43,6:27,7:388,8:1,9:219,10:3
</usr/local/share/fonts/t/times.ttf></usr/local/share/fonts/t/TrajanPro_Bold.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 24507 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.

And if I also add \bfseries, it even uses the TTF file TrajanPro_Regular.ttf for the bold series. Funny but not what we expect.
Explicitly telling fontspec which file to use for which series helps whenever the automatism fails:
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times}
\newfontfamily{\trajan}{TrajanPro_Regular.ttf}[BoldFont=TrajanPro_Bold.otf]

\title{{\trajan The Wind Blows}} % Here \normalfont uses Times font, not Trajan

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\trajan Trajan and \textbf{Trajan Bold}
    
\end{document}


Note 1: The automatic font select also can depend on using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. With XeLaTeX already
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\trajan}{Trajan Pro}

\title{{\trajan The Wind Blows}} % Here \normalfont uses Times font, not Trajan

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\trajan Trajan and \textbf{Trajan Bold}
\end{document}

has the correct result.
Note 2: If you want to know the loaded font files, when using XeLaTeX, you can use xelatex -no-pdf foo to generate a foo.xdv instead of foo.pdf from foo.tex. Then use xdvipdfmx -v foo.xdv to generate foo.pdf. The terminal output again shows information about the fonts loaded, e.g.:
/usr/local/share/fonts/t/TrajanPro_Bold.otf[CIDFontType0]


Thank you. In my code, updating the line \newfontfamily{\trajan}[BoldFont=TrajanPro_Bold.otf]{Trajan Pro Regular} works as intended. I did not know that the the log file contains this information. Thanks very much.

@ellat I've added some more information about how to see, which font files are loaded when using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.
